# How to show that the difference of two Gumbel distributed random variables makes a Logistic distribution?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

How to show that, for two random variables X∼Gumbel[a,b] and Y∼Gumbel[c,b], X−Y∼Logistic[a-c,b]?
Can anyone show step by step how to make solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characteristic function of  Gumbel RVs are $\phi_X(t)=\Gamma(1-ibt)e^{iat}$ and $\phi_Y(t)=\Gamma(1-ibt)e^{ict}$ respectively. Then, if the RVs are independent:

$$\phi_{X-Y}(t)=\mathbf{E}[e^{t(X-Y)}]=\phi_X(t)\phi_Y(-t)=\Gamma(1-ibt)\Gamma(1+ibt)e^{i(a-c)t}=\frac{\pi bt}{\sinh(\pi b t)}e^{i(a-c)t}$$

and this is the characteristic function of a logistic RV with parameters $a-c$ and $b$.